# Nesting callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm not so experienced in async javascript. How can I call the commands without hardcoding the amount of commands or using eval?

```js
var commands = [
    // command 1: result: 0, stdout: ""
    function (stdin, callback) {
        callback(0, "");
    },
    // command 2: result: 1, stdout: ""
    function (stdin, callback) {
        callback(1, "");
    },
    // command 3: result: 0, stdout: ""
    function (stdin, callback) {
        callback(0, "");
    },
    // ...
];

var stdin = "foo";
var end = function (result, stdout) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(stdout);
};

commands[0](stdin, function (result, stdout) {
    commands[1](stdout, function (result, stdout) {
        commands[2](stdout, end);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just because it's callbacks, it doesn't mean its asynchronous, so I'm having a hard time figuring out why you really need this. You should clarify why you need this, I'm tempted to vote to close even though I voted it up initially... Is this purely a hypothetical?

Comment: It looks like you want some sort of queuing behavior.

Comment: By the way, the code doesn't do anything that I can make sense of... http://jsfiddle.net/eJS3m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final answer:**

I'm using recursion to go through the commands array.
You pass the loop function an array of commands and the last callback to be called (you can also pass as a fourth optional parameter the index of the array in which you wish to start the loop - defaults to zero).

```
var commands = [
    // echo foo
    function (stdin, callback) {
        callback(0, "foo");
    },
    // touppercase
    function (stdin, callback) {
        callback(1, stdin.toUpperCase());
    }
];

var stdin   = "",
    loop    = function(commands, lastCallback, stdin, startIndex) {
        (function insideLoop(i, stdout) {
            commands[i](stdout, (i + 1 < commands.length) ? function(result, stdout){ insideLoop(i + 1, stdout); } : lastCallback); 
        })(startIndex || 0, stdin);
    },
    end     = function (result, stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
    };

loop(commands, end, stdin);
```

**[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xuyGT/2/)**

Comment: How about finishing it up by letting you pass in the commands array?

Comment: Thanks! I'm building something like a shell and this code executes commands in a pipe (for example "foo | bar | baz") and chains stdin and stdout.

Comment: You are correct. Use this http://jsfiddle.net/xuyGT/2/ while I'll fix the answer :)

Comment: I forgot to add the `result, stdout` parameters to the anonymous function. It works now, you can see the live code example. One last thing, I can seem to understand `result` purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To let those functions run *asyncronously*, you need a way to invoke them by making sure that inbetween the calls, a browser (or actually any implementation) is allowed to do other stuff and things (cleanups, reflows, etc.).

That can be done with `.setTimeout` in browsers or `.nextTick` in nodejS.

```
function runAsync( list ) {
    (function _worker( method ) {
        method();

        if( list.length ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                _worker( list.shift() );
            }, 100);
        }
    }( list.shift() ));
}
```

This would get called like

```
runAsync( commands );
```

and it would succesive grab the next array-entry (which is assumed a function) and execute it. After that, we check if there are more elements in that entry and if so, grab the next and call the next function. That happens within a `setTimeout` call and a delay of *100ms*. I choosed *100ms* here, because its pretty much the timeframe which human beeings won't see any "slow-down" or "lagging".

Comment: I don't think this answers what the OP is asking.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't, but the OP is not very clear what about what is needed, see my comment under the question

Comment: Hmm, yea we might have a case of "fail" here on my part.